# Errors importing React-Router, using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'm trying to use react-router with the create-react-app I just created but I'm having issues importing it. I'm importing it like I import the other react dependencies:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

but I'm getting this error message:

```
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom' in 'C:\Users\Eric\Code\react-test\src'
```

I've tried googling and checking on here but I can't find an answer. Why isn't it looking in node_modules?

Comment: Is your react-router-dom in the dependencies in your package.js ?

Answer (score 0):

### Install `react-router-dom`.

I got this error message because I had followed an old tutorial that had me installing the `react-router` packager instead of `react-router-dom` package. Couldn't figure it out for a little bit.

To solve this issue, just install `react-router-dom`:

```
npm install --save react-router-dom
```

All set!